# facebook social sharing not working

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to make sure that Facebook social sharing works for a blog article that I'm going to write, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The site that needs to be shared is at: https://www.ivanteong.com/blog/cybersecurity-dummies.html

It keeps ending up with:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /blog/a href= was not found on this server.
```

The code in question used is:

```
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ivanteong.com%2Fblog%2Fcybersecurity-dummies.html" target="_blank""><img class="img-responsive " src="../images/sharing-icons/facebook.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/sharing-icons/hover/facebook.png';" onmouseout="this.src='../images/sharing-icons/facebook.png';" alt="Image"></a></li>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: The heroku site being shared is down btw.

Comment: `<li><a href="a href="https://www.[...]` - and that did not look suspicious to you at all …?

Comment: Typo - the code didn't have a href="a href", I pasted it twice here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ivanteong.com%2Fblog%2Fcybersecurity-dummies.html" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive " src="../images/sharing-icons/facebook.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/sharing-icons/hover/facebook.png';" onmouseout="this.src='../images/sharing-icons/facebook.png';" alt="Image"></a></li>
```